# Cannot install paprefs on mac os

Tags: macos, pulse-audio

I want to stream my microphone from my Mac OS to my Oracle cloud instance which is using Ubuntu 20. Maybe also backwards as well (stream container sound back to the local computer). I connect to the cloud instance using SSH. I think this is correct way to do it (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470961/how-to-set-up-pulseaudio-remote-properly-and-securely)
For me, the problem is pulse audio is not designed for Mac OS. It is designed to work for 2 linux systems (I could be wrong). I could install pulse audio on Mac OS using `brew install pulseaudio`. However, I believe this only allow me to enable or disable modules of pulse audio. To actually stream it to output stream, I would need another software called paprefs. This is not found on brew. It is probably not compatible with Mac OS anyway. So is a work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely paprefs was excluded because it relies on PulseAudio's support for the GNOME *GSettings* framework. You don't actually need it though – literally *all* it does is tell PulseAudio to load modules, which can be done through its standard `default.pa` startup script as well. The article that you linked to already documents the exact modules needed on the server as well as the client.

PA is architectured similarly to X11. Connections, both capture and playback, are initiated by PulseAudio on the "client" side (i.e. where programs like Audacity or Discord are running). On your local (macOS) machine, PulseAudio only accepts inbound connections – it can't make outbound ones to "offer" the microphone – so there isn't much that you need to configure anyway.

To move streams from one output to another, you'd need `pavucontrol` (or `pavucontrol-qt`), but this is done on the source (your Ubuntu server), and can also be achieved using `pactl` anyway.